# How to turn Mac OS X Lion into a web server?

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

After using MAMP for ages, I found out I could actually use Snow Leopard's built-in Apache server. Now that I've upgraded to Lion, I have no idea how to do this anymore.

Do you know how to turn my Mac OS X Lion into a web server, so that I can easily run the latest version of PHP and MySQL in it? Also, how do I set the "localhost" aliases? I remember it was a httpd.conf file — something that I don't seem to find anymore on Lion.

Comment: Just a little help for GUI editor lovers:
For using TextMate as default editor from Terminal you can call it as `mate`. sudo mate /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
It is a good idea to register it in ~/.bash_profile for that purpose before the 1st use: export EDITOR='mate -w' And create a symlink in your ~/bin folder: ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate ~/bin/mate **The above info applies to Mac OS X users*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You first need to enable Apache in the Sharing prefpane. Check "Web sharing" and your web server is running.

**Note that since Mountain Lion**, Web Sharing was removed from the Sharing preference pane, but Apache is still included. Check [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66358/enabling-apache-in-mac-os-x-mountaion-lion#66361) for controlling Apache in Mountain Lion.

[image: Enable Web Sharing]

To activate PHP you'll need to edit `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` in Terminal.app. This requires root credentials. `nano` is a very accessible command-line editor if you are uncomfortable with `vim`.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Find the line (you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to start searching in `nano`):

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

and uncomment it. Next find the line

```
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and uncomment that as well to enable virtual hosts support.

Save the file and exit `nano` by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, then confirming the changes by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd>(es), then <kbd>enter</kbd>.

You can now edit your virtual hosts in the file `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Important to note is that the first defined host will be the default host for unqualified host names. For resolving additional hostnames apart from `localhost` I recommend hardcoding them in `/etc/hosts`.

To install MySQL, download the installer from the MySQL website (64bit installer should be ok). Follow the instructions to install it.

Finally, to configure PHP for MySQL, copy the default `php.ini`:

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

Now you can edit `/etc/php.ini` (again root access required) and replace any reference to `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` with `/tmp/mysql.sock` (the default location of the MySQL socket after running the installer). There probably are about 3 references to that path.

Finally, restart Apache for the new configuration to take effect:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Alternatively you can restart Apache by toggling it off and on again in the Sharing prefpane.

Done.

Comment: i would advise you to never suggest any sort of terminal text editor, just use textedit.app in the command instead of nano, because terminal text editors are just barbaric.

Comment: Nano is quite user-friendly, IMO, and it's really annoying to try to edit something with root privileges from the GUI.

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX: I'm sorry but that's just bad advice. If anything, you'll find it next to impossible to edit these files in TextEdit.app because a lack of privileges, as NReilingh also pointed out. Also, it is not unreasonable to expect some aquaintance with the console from any (aspiring) web developer.

Comment: generally works if u sudo it

Comment: Did you try that out @XAleXOwnZX?

Comment: yeah but it might be cuz i gave my account root permissions xD, i'll try it later

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX: With all due respect, that is arguably the worst advice I have ever seen on a Stack Exchange property. I agree that a GUI text editor is probably a better approach for people who are not programmers or who don't have much unix experience, however, TextEdit is the wrong application to advise using simply because it defaults to a variable-width font and rich text. This can cause all sorts of problems (beyond the simple usability nightmare of writing code in variable-width) that will be extremely difficult or impossible for this person to debug.

Comment: well obv you'd switch to plain text mode… (if it wasn't already since textedit switches to plain text when opening regular .txts)

Comment: I believe this is much easier in Lion Server.  These days the price of that is reasonable even for hobby projects.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen depends on the purpose. For a web dev box I find OS X Server overkill, and you'd still have to deal with config files to accomplish everything anyway.

Comment: In which universe is a terminal editor "barbaric", imho TextEdit.app is barbaric. I'd (tongue in cheek) expect some smarty pants vi(m) or sed replies, I'd only expect TextEdit from a Windows user.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, an alternative to MAMP is [WebStart](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/products/webstart/overview/)  that makes it easy to manage a professional Apache 2 web sever on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion.

Answer (score -2):

You can find [a good tutorial here](http://jannaud.fr/mamp-mac-os-lion) to enable also phpmyadmin and such without using mamp

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.