# Where is MySQL installed for the included Apache server?

Tags: apache, mysql

I'm trying to set up Web Sharing... phpinfo() shows MySQL is installed, but I can't find it. Terminal says "command not found" when I try mysql.

I have no idea what I'm doing, or even if this question makes sense.

Comment: I've found this guide on installing MySQL (et al.) to the best of the bunch (and I've followed a few of them over the years): http://www.applefritter.com/snowleopard-wordpress Just stop at Wordpress if you don't want it. The rest is quick, painless, and dead simple.

Comment: @cksum Thanks, I installed it and Sequel Pro now works and what not. But when I try `mysql [anything]` in Terminal, I just get `bash: mysql: command not found`. Do I have to do something else to enable that? Or, uh, be in a certain directory? I've tried the apache directory & the directory that houses the socket.

Comment: OK, I'm guessing it's a $PATH problem, and in any case I guess you can circumvent it by specifying a full path for the command. Total beginner in all things here. Working on it. :)

Comment: @Toph Edit the file /etc/paths.d/mysql with root priviliges (it probably doesn't exist yet) and put "/usr/local/mysql/bin" as content.

Comment: Thanks Gerry. [padding so my comment is long enough, ha]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL is not installed by default, even though the included PHP is compiled with MySQL support. Check out [this guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/how-to-turn-mac-os-x-lion-into-a-web-server/23757#23757) for MySQL installation.

Comment: @Toph. See also http://www.apple.com/opensource/ which is the list of open-source software that is preinstalled on Mac OS X. As you can see, MySQL is not there, while there are PostgreSQL and SQLite, with the latter only in Mac OS X client version (= not in server version).

Comment: @ignis There is no such thing as a SQLite server :)

Comment: Yeah, what I meant is "in Mac OS X client version (= not in Mac OS X server version)".

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the terminal, and typing `locate mysql`.

If you've never used locate before, it will index your drive first; in which case you might need to "sudo locate" and wait five minutes before re-trying.

For the documentation, type `man locate` and `man locate.updatedb`.