# How do I enable PHP on Mountain Lion OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, apache, php

Just upgraded to Mountain Lion, and wanted to make PHP work on the built-in version of Apache.

Comment: The same way as in previous versions. Check http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/how-to-turn-mac-os-x-lion-into-a-web-server/23757#23757

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Edit `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
2. Find the line that says `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` and uncomment it by editing out the # at the beginning of the line. (Then save the file, obviously.)
3. Go to Terminal and type `sudo apachectl graceful` at the console:

Comment: I highly doubt that Apple provides an up-to-date PHP version for this.