# Install Apache, PHP and MySQL on Mac w/o MacPorts?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, apache, mysql, php

For some reason I can't use MacPorts. So the question is if it's possible to install Apache, PHP and MySQL on Snow Leopard w/o using MacPorts?

Please don't offer MAMP or other bundles.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don’t you want MAMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Apache and PHP already come by default with a Mac OS X installation, and you can download an installer for MySQL on their website.

For a configuration guide, have a look at this related answer:

[How to turn Mac OS X Lion into a web server?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/how-to-turn-mac-os-x-lion-into-a-web-server/23757#23757)

The linked answer also applies to Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Another popular (and imo superior) way of running development environments is running a Linux server with your preferred configuration in a VirtualBox virtual machine. [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) makes this workflow even easier. This is a very flexible solution, as you can easily add custom extensions and more specifically for one project, without messing with one centralized install.