# Enabling Apache in Mac OS X Mountaion Lion

Tags: macos, apache

This is my first Mac, it's Mountain Lion, and I know how to enable Apache through Preferences -> Sharing -> Web Sharing, but how the hell do I do it in Mountain Lion?

I find that that button no longer exists, so what's the Ternimal command to turn it on manually?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To start apache
`sudo apachectl start`

This will give you a basic Apache server with a DocumentRoot at  `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`

You can enable things like PHP and virtualhosts by making use of the configuration file, which must be edited as root:
`/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Restart the apache server (like after editing the config file) with
`sudo apachectl graceful`

Stop the apache server
`sudo apachectl graceful-stop`

I believe in order to use user directories (like allowing `~/Sites/` to be accessed at `http://localhost/~username/`) or to get httpd to run at startup, you will need to do a little tweaking. I unfortunately can't test how easy it is to get the full functionality of the previous versions back since my Apache configs did not come from a "clean" 10.8 install.

Comment: Awesome! This is more than enough! Thanks a lot. :) If you do find out how to configure the use of `~/Sites/` then please tell me. ;)

Comment: Some preliminary poking seems to indicate it has to do with making sure mod_userdir is active and that `/etc/apache2/extras/httpd-userdir.conf` is being properly imported at the end of the main configuration file. If `~/Sites` already exists, that _may_ be all you have to do...

Comment: OK, I'll check it out then, thanks for all your help. :)

Comment: The only thing that changed when I unpgraded was my custom *.conf directory was nixed from the /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf file. I ran `/>httpd -S` from Terminal and it pointed out the error of my ways.

Answer (score 4):

To make it permanent you can do this:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

the '-w' option sets it to restart the service on rebooting etc.