# How do I get Web Sharing back on Mountain Lion?

Tags: apache, web-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enabling Apache in Mac OS X Mountaion Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66358/enabling-apache-in-mac-os-x-mountaion-lion)

Like the title says but with a twist.

I DO NOT want to use localhost, but my internal IP instead so I don't want to use all the tutorials I have seen to restart/configure Apache from the command line to get localhost working. **Reason:**

I need the IP to test through multiple devices on my network. With localhost, this is just not possible per every device.

Thanks,

Marco

Comment: Your twist is irrelevant, Apache listens to all IP addresses on your machine by default. If you have a specific problem configuring Apache once it is running, please rephrase your question to address that.

Comment: I got it to work. Problem was I needed to uncomment:

LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Now it works like a charm with my IP, etc the way it was :)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using [MAMP](http://mamp.info), as it's just as easy as Web Sharing was before.

Comment: I do, but this one I use for Wordpress :) THANKS!!!

Comment: Why wouldn't MAMP work for WordPress?