# Running a local web server on MacBook

Tags: macos, webserver

I am using a MacBook with OS X Mounain Lion 10.8.3 and I want to install a local web server on my machine. What are my options? On windows I used XAMPP.

Comment: I wouldn't install anything, but just turn it on... Here is a [duplicate question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/66358/55567) with a decent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the stuff you need is already installed by default, or can be added easily. There is a lot of material on the web about [how to do this](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+apache+and+mysql+on+osx), [this article](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/) seems to cover the basics.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want something very quick, the [OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com) article [Create an Instant Web Server via Terminal Command Line](http://osxdaily.com/2010/05/07/create-an-instant-web-server-via-terminal-command-line/) explains how to do this on the command line using Python. Its pretty much just using the command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Comment: In Python3, [that would be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943751/what-is-the-python-3-equivalent-of-python-m-simplehttpserver) `python3 -m http.server`.

Comment: Also note that the server will run on port `8000` by default, as ports below 1024 require superuser privileges.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in running Apache, PHP, MySQL and phpMyAdmin, you can check out [this article](http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion).

Or just use [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)

Comment: Of the two which is the best?

Comment: We don't know what "best" means for you. If you have specific requirements please add them *to your question* by editing it.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, there is a simple `XAMPP` like solution called [`MAMP`](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) which comes as both a free and a paid version. The free version will suit most people. Just like `XAMPP` this will provide you with Apache, PHP and MySQL, and also PhpMyAdmin/

If you just want to serve a simple html page, with no underlying PHP or anything you could use Python's [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html), with the following `bash` function that you can put in your ~/.bash_profile:

```
function servedir {
    local port="${1:-80}"
    open "http://localhost:${port}/"
    sudo python -c $'import SimpleHTTPServer;\nmap = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map;\nmap[""] = "text/plain";\nfor key, value in map.items():\n\tmap[key] = value + ";charset=UTF-8";\nSimpleHTTPServer.test();' "$port"
}
```

With the `servedir` `bash` function, you simple change to the directory you want to serve, type `servedir` and then it will open your web browser at `http://localhost` so you can see your page.