# How to serve the personal website from different folder?

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

So far, I [read on MacRumors](http://guides.macrumors.com/Personal_Web_Sharing) of:

> #### System-wide site
>
> Files at `/Library/WebServer/Documents` will, by default, be shared as the root Web site when Web sharing is turned on. These files can be accessed at `http://localhost/` or `http://<yourIPaddress>`.
>
> #### User-specific sites
>
> Files at `~/Sites`, or in your home folder's Sites folder, are considered your user-specific site files. Each user by default has one of these folders. Each user's site can be accessed at `http://<yourIPaddress>/~(shortusername)`.

It's all depicted when activating Web Sharing:

[image: Web Sharing]

But my static files are in a different folder, so I would like to serve them from `~/Projects/js-spa` instead of from `~/Sites`, but reading about [configuring Apache](http://guides.macrumors.com/Personal_Web_Sharing), I can't find `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` on Lion.

How can I configure where do I want to serve the personal website from?

Comment: If you're up for it, httpd.conf should be in /etc/apache2/ on Lion/ML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're up for it, httpd.conf should be in /etc/apache2/ on Lion/ML. Some mac-centred help is at [this blog](http://www.petersena.com/blog/technology/websharing-macosx-localhost/).

Have a look at "[How to turn Mac OS X Lion into a web server?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23751/how-to-turn-mac-os-x-lion-into-a-web-server/23757#23757)" for instructions on the Web Sharing pane, and doing similar things in Terminal under Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

[As Cathy mentioned](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/77385/14117), you can accomplish this in Lion/Mountain Lion in just 3 easy steps:

1. open `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` in your favourite editor (`sudo` it)
2. search for

   - `DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"` and
   - `<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">`

   and replace `/Library/WebServer/Documents` with the path you want Apache to serve for *localhost*, e.g., `/Users/<username>/Projects`
3. restart Apache: `sudo apachectl restart`